# How to redirect from a TaskList to a sitepage in sharepoint Spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, spfx, sharepoint-framework

This is my Task list, how to redirect to any Site page on the click of the Task Name field?

[image]

When we are clicking on any Task Name field's value, the default form is opening as shown below:

[image]

Instead of opening the default form, we want to redirect to any Site page form, as shown below:

[image]

Is there any way, to give the URL to redirect to the Site page form instead of default form opening in the Task list in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSR to re-render the list view.

```
<script>
  (function(){
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want     to change it's output render
    var statusFiledContext= {};
    statusFiledContext.Templates = {};
    statusFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {
      //Apply the new redenring for nom du projet field on the list view
      "Title" : {"View" : statusFiledTemplate}
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFiledContext);
  })();
  
  //this function provides our purpose
  function statusFiledTemplate(ctx){
    var task= ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    return "<a href='https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/page.aspx'>" + task + "</a>"; 
  }
</script>
```

[image]